# Implementing multi-lang support in pyrocms

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have been trying to implement multi-lang support based on Sazans library, but the query doesn't seem to be working for me.

The library: https://github.com/sazan/MultiLang-Library-for-PyroCMS/blob/master/README

My error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`default_navigation_links`) WHERE `navigation_group_id` = '1' ORDER BY `p' at line 2

SELECT *, translate("navigation", `id`, `"title"`, `"en"`, `title)` AS title FROM (`default_navigation_links`) WHERE `navigation_group_id` = '1' ORDER BY `position`
```

The error is getting thrown cause of the query. I believe that the function translate isn't defined and that's why it throws an error.

```
The query: $this->db ->select('*, translate("navigation", id, "title", "'.CURRENT_LANGUAGE.'", title) AS title');
```

I tried running the function setup query (the one found in the projects page) on my database through phpmyadmin. When I was adding it - it didn't return a error and it didn't "tell me" that it succeeded adding the function.

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the function, it is related to Active Record class of CI. CI AR class automatically escapes the fields you select using `$this->db ->select(...)`. So to use my stored function you'll have to turn auto escaping off by setting second param of AR's select function to false:

```
$this->db->select('*, translate("navigation", id, "title", "'.CURRENT_LANGUAGE.'", title) AS title', false);
```

And it will work. Cheers!